# Прокомментируйте как получаем значение?

Tags: javascript

```js
function ask(question, answer, ok, fail) {
  var result = prompt(question, '');
  if (result.toLowerCase() == answer.toLowerCase()) ok();
  else fail();
}

var user = {
  login: 'Василий',
  password: '12345',

  // метод для вызова из ask
  loginDone: function(result) {
    alert( this.login + (result ? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа') );
  },

  checkPassword: function() {
   var self = this;
    ask("Ваш пароль?", this.password,
      function() {
        self.loginDone(true);
      },
      function() {
        self.loginDone(false);
      }
    );
  }
};

var vasya = user;
user = null;
vasya.checkPassword()
```

в ask мы передаем  из свойства  checkPassword значения;
В question получит "Ваш пароль?";
answer получит  password - 12345,
А дальше не могу понять как тернарный оператор возвращает вошел поселитель на сайт или нет ?

Comment: `loginDone` вызывается с разным значением параметра из `ok` и из `fail`

Comment: @Igor если условия в if верно  то срабатывает код ok в котором self.loginDone(true); будет function(result) {
    alert( this.login + (result ? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа') );
  }, с параметром true верно ?

Comment: да, верно *(6 символов нужно...)*

Comment: @Igor что за 6 символов ?

Comment: слишком короткий комментарий получался

Comment: @Igor дальше не понятно если мы передали true будет такая запись function(result) {
    alert( this.login + (result ? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа') );
  }, где аргумент будет true

Comment: function(true) {
    alert( this.login + (true? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа') );
  },

Comment: а дальше чета я запнулся ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loginDone` вызывается с разным значением параметра `result` из `ok` и из `fail`.

Если в тернарном операторе условие `true`, то он возвращает первый операнд. Если `false`, то второй.

```js
console.log(true? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа');
console.log(false? ' вошёл в сайт' : ' ошибка входа');
```

Comment: ок спасибо теперь понятно